# How to use ctx.clearRect on specific drawings only?

Tags: canvas

Let´s say I wrote a towerdefense game. Now I want to delete/clear the destroyed towers. I can do that by using

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

However I have to call

```
setIntervall(drawAllTowers, 100)
```

to draw the functional towers "back again"(I stored the drawing coordinates of the towers in an array, which is getting looped through, when accessing *drawAllTowers*).

I´m pretty sure there is another solution to it, right? I searched the forums and found out however, that the idea behind ctx.clearRect is redrawing everything, after it gets cleared. It works, yes, but it´s laggy and it flickers alot.

Is there a better way to solve this problem? :)